# Login via Shell Script

Tags: ssh

My issue is that I want run a script from root for which I always have to login with root manually by typing "su -" on command line.

My query is that the script which I am executing it automatically login with root by just prompting me for password. Help me!!!

::::::::::Script:::::::::::::

```
if [ "$(whoami)" != "root" ]; then

echo -e '\E[41m'"\033[1mYou must be root to run this script\033[0m"

**su - # at this line I want to login as root but it is not working**

exit 1

fi

sleep 1

if [ "$(pwd)" != "/root" ]; then

echo -e '\E[41m'"\033[1mCopy this script to /root & then try again\033[0m"

cd /root

exit 1

fi

sleep 1

echo -e '\E[36;45m'"\033[1mDownloading Flash Player from ftp.etilizepak.com\033[0m"

sleep 2

wget -vcxr ftp://soft:S0ft\!@ftp.abc.com/ubuntu/ubuntu\ 12.04/adobe-flashplugin=/install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz

cd ftp.abc.com/ubuntu/ubuntu\ 12.04/adobe-flashplugin/

sleep 1

echo -e '\E[42m'"\033[1mUnzipping .tar File...\033[0m"

sleep 1

tar -xzf install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz

echo "Unzipping Compeleted"

sleep 2

echo -e '\E[42m'"\033[1mCopying libflashplayer.so\033[0m"

cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins/
```

:::::::::::::::END:::::::::::::::::::::

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question but I suppose you want to run something inside you script with root privileges - then you shuold use "sudo" command.
You can also suppress the password prompt, this can be configured in sudoers" configuration file.

Some more info here:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/35338/su-vs-sudo-s-vs-sudo-bash
[Shell script calls sudo; how do I suppress the password prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111702/shell-script-calls-sudo-how-do-i-suppress-the-password-prompt)

There is tons of examples, google something like "linux sudo examples" and you will get lots of examples how to use su, sudo ans sudoers commands.

Comment: You should cut all lines that must be run as root and put it inside another .sh file, then in the first script write: sudo /path/to/your/script.sh. Similar question  here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1988249/how-do-i-use-su-to-execute-the-rest-of-the-bash-script-as-that-user

Comment: but in my scenario I can not give sudo rights to the users all the time because this script is used usually at different users. So please give me the appropriate solution.

Comment: You can give sudo right for **this script only**, please read my second answer

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments to my previous answer, here is how i do it:

**There are two files in the same directory:**

```
-rwx------ 1 root root 19 Sep 10 13:04 test2.sh
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Sep 10 13:06 test.sh
```

**File test.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
# put your message here
su -c ./test2.sh
```

**File test2.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash
echo You run as:
whoami
# put your code here
```

**Result:**

```
> ./test.sh
Password:****
You run as:
root
```

If you want to suppress the password prompt **for this script only**, replace "su -c" with "sudo" and configure sudoers file according to insctructions from here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/155791/how-do-i-sudo-a-command-in-a-script-without-being-asked-for-a-password