# how to switch to root user without entering password in bash script on RedHat

Tags: linux, bash, root, redhat

I want to switch to root user in bash script on RedHat by specifying the password in code rather than entering it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's not a good idea to store passwords in plain text in a script. You can use `visudo` to edit the `sudoers` file and allow users to run a command using `sudo` without using a password.

Answer (score 4):

The flexibility of sudo is widely under-estimated. This leads to very poor practices (like the `sudo su -` canon-ball surgery method).

**A much better method is to specificly allow the commands you intend to allow *without use of a password***:

```
phill = NOPASSWD: /bin/ls, /usr/bin/lprm
```

---

See for more examples: [Shell script - Sudo-permissions lost over time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866767/shell-script-sudo-permissions-lost-over-time/6198418#6198418)

Answer (score 1):

Let sudo read from stdin using the -S flag

```
sudo -S mkdir /mnt/somedir <<END 
password here

END
```

This will let a user create a directory in /mnt owned by root

EDIT: this doesn't seem to work for the "su" command, yet I think this solution might be helpful

Comment: @user1433243: `<<END` is the beginning of a [here document](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html#lbBO) and in the last line `END` is the end of it.