# Check if Root user exist in AWS account

Tags: python

I want to check if root user exist in AWS account using Python or any cli command.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands

`aws iam list-users`

`aws iam list-roles`

Comment: Hi Santosh... thank for your reply. By using these commands how will I know which user is Root user.

Comment: Hi RAcharya, using this command you can list all the users and user roles separately. Please go ahead and test this.
If this doesn't answer your query then try this command to switch to root user
sudo su -    

for more detail, you can read these two stack answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10882310/how-to-switch-to-root-user-without-entering-password-in-bash-script-on-redhat

or

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5866767/shell-script-sudo-permissions-lost-over-time/6198418#6198418

Comment: Hi Santosh...I mean Root user of AWS not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Every AWS account has a [root user](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_root-user.html). It cannot be deleted. There is no need to test for the presence of this.

If you're able to retrieve the access key for the root user programmatically (e.g. on the CLI or with boto), then you must be signing the request with the root key, which implies that the account has a root user access key.

Comment: Hi Owen.. thank you for your reply. I know each account has root user but some customer delete the Root user for safety purpose. So I want to know whether a given AWS account has Root user or not.

Comment: You cannot delete the root user. You can, however, delete the access key for the root user. Is this what you want to check for?